# Table Odd Even tr backgroundcolor on specific class

Tags: html, css

I would like to change the background color of odd tr only of .headcol class.

.headcol is a sticky column on left.

```css
thead th {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  font-family: Poppins-Thin, sans-serif;
}

.headcol {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.headcol tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table class="table" id="TabListing">
 <thead class="thead-dark">
   <th class="headcol">Nom</th>
   <th>Prénom</th>
 </thead>

<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td class="headcol">BAR</td>
  <td>Mohamed</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td class="headcol">BIAI</td>
 <td>Ikrame</td>
 </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

This code don't give me anything...

If I try :

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Odd tr are blue but not .headcol

Comment: The problem is that you are looking to style `tr` elements only if they _contain_ an element with the `.headcol` class.  This is effectively asking for a "parent selector", and it [doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text) [exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector).  You might need to leverage JS, or consider a different way for structuring/classing this data.

Comment: Can you help me about JS ?

Comment: Actually, perhaps I misunderstood your requirements. To clarify-- you need every other instance of a `.headcol` `td` to be blue?  Or the whole `tr` that it occupies?

Comment: I want .headcol of odd tr to be in blue! Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you were close.  But remember-- the selector item on the left is assumed to *contain* the selector item to the right (unless some specific operator is placed between them in the selector to change the relationship).  So this:

```css
.headcol tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

...was describing every odd `tr` inside of an element with class `.headcol`, which is never reflected in your markup.  Instead, you want to select any `.headcol`-classed element inside of an odd-numbered `tr`, which would be:

```css
tr:nth-child(odd) .headcol {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

This is what I have done in the below snippet, which appears to match your requirements, if I am understanding them correctly.

```css
thead th {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  font-family: Poppins-Thin, sans-serif;
}

.headcol {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) .headcol {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table class="table" id="TabListing">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <th class="headcol">Nom</th>
        <th>Prénom</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="headcol">BAR</td>
            <td>Mohamed</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="headcol">BIAI</td>
            <td>Ikrame</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="headcol">BIAI</td>
            <td>Alex</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="headcol">BIAI</td>
            <td>Clement</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="headcol">BIAI</td>
            <td>Rachel</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you!! that's what I want!

Comment: Why THEAD is also in bue ?

Comment: I solved the problem by replacing odd by even ! Works very well! thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I make correct code for you:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
thead th {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  font-family: Poppins-Thin, sans-serif;
}

.headcol {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table" id="TabListing">
 <thead class="thead-dark">
   <th class="headcol">Nom</th>
   <th>Prénom</th>
 </thead>

<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td class="headcol">BAR</td>
  <td>Mohamed</td>
 </tr>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td class="headcol">BIAl</td>
  <td>Ikrame</td>
 </tr>

</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As you can see when you click on Run Code snippet, your answer don't work, I need only odd headcol in blue!